# Anaconda Spyder 4.1.4 not creating folders properly in project hierarchie

Tags: anaconda, spyder

Anaconda with Python 3.8.
Spyder 4.1.4

When i open Spyder and then i go to `Projects` -> `New Project` and when I create a new project in `C:/Users/UserA/myproject` and I right-click on the root folder `myproject` in my project explorer and want to create a new folder `foo` so that `foo` is a subfolder of `myproject` then the folder `foo` is created in `C:/Users/UserA` instead of `C:/Users/UserA/myproject`. This behavior is independent of whether I use an existing folder for a new project or create a new one. This behaviour has never been observed before (at least I haven't read a single post in any forum about it). I would be grateful for help. I just want to have the following absolute path for my folder `foo`, which I created in the Project Explorer in Spyder `C:/Users/UserA/myproject/foo`. Instead I get `C:/Users/UserA/foo`. Of course I checked the working directory in Spyder in the address line in the upper right corner. After I created the new project, the path is up correctly: `C:/Users/UserA/myproject`. But still new folders are created in `C:/Users/UserA/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't fix the problem, but the folders are created correctly if you don't use the project explorer on the left side, but the file explorer pane ("`Files`") on the right side and create new folders there by right clicking.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This was due to an error and it's going to be fixed in our next version.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Ok. :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I removed the last sentence to make your answer more useful.